# How would one generate a WSDL file from a UML diagram?

Tags: wsdl, xsd, uml

I know that RSA and RAD(IBM products) are good tools for generating wsdl and schema from UML model diagrams. However these tools are costly. I have done some search and found that hypermodel tool(free) is a good tool for generating UML class diagrams from schemas and wsdls.

http://www.xmlmodeling.com/hypermodel

However is there a free tool which can generate a WSDL file and XML schema from UML model diagrams(reverse of above), something similar to RSA or RAD (something similar to these tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) has facilities for WSDL modelling, including forward and reverse engineering. I don't have any real experience with this myself, but in general EA is a very good modelling tool indeed.

It's not free, but the Professional edition (which you need for WSDL models) only costs US$199 for a single license. You can also get an all-functionality one-month trial for free.